# What is the difference between a "semi-contracted" muscle and a "contracted" muscle?

Tags: terminology, muscles

I read on http://www.spine-health.com/glossary/muscle-tension:

> Muscle tension refers to the condition in which muscles of the body remain **semi-contracted** for an extended period.

What is the difference between a "semi-contracted" muscle and a "contracted" muscle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the length of a muscle can vary from resting length to shortest length, my guess is that semi-contracted is somewhere in between. I believe that spine-health.com isn't being entirely clear with their definitions.

Comment: I think they're refering to rate coding and motor unit recruitment.